# My Laravel App on AWS EB always occurs Permission denied Error after Lambda function restarts it

Tags: laravel, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

On AWS, I've set CloudWatch events to trigger Lambda functions which stop/restart Elastic Beanstalk environment where my Laravel + docker-compose app sits in. However, after restarting, my Laravel app occurs an Error;

```
The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I can fix this error rather easily, by using eb cli. All I have to do is connect to the app, go into a docker container and run the following command;

```
chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Hoevever...do I have to do this every morning!?
Is there a way to avoid `Permission denied` Error after restarting? Or is there a way to automate the above two commands? If anyone could shed some lights on it, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: It sounds like you need to add those two commands to your `Dockerfile` you are using to build your docker image. If you are having to go into your docker container to fix something every time you create a container from an image, then you should fix it in the image.

Comment: thank you for your advice. I'll give it a try!

Comment: @MarkB Your solution worked nicely!! Thank you very much!!